# Address of Dragged File in Windows

Tags: python, windows, path, drag

How can I know what is the address of dragged file or folder in windows explorer with Python?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? This doesn't really help us answer your question.

Comment: What is an "address" when related to a file or a folder? Do you mean the source path?

Comment: I thought Windows shell objects are not required to have a file path..  After all, what is "My Computer"?  It doesn't have a node in the filesystem.  I'm pretty sure you can write shell extensions that add stuff that don't correspond to filesystem objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think the filename path, the function that handles a 'drop' normally has a struct with the data you need, but python itself does not provides a gui to drop files, what widget framework are you using?